# Python regex - Extract all the matching text between two patterns

Tags: python, regex, text, text-mining

I want to extract all the text in the bullet points numbered as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc. Sometimes the bullet points can have space like 1. 1, 1. 2, 1 .3, 1 . 4

Sample text

```
    text = "some text before pattern 1.1 text_1_here  1.2 text_2_here  1 . 3 text_3_here  1. 4 text_4_here  1 .5 text_5_here 1.10 last_text_here 1.23 text after pattern"
```

For the text above, the output should be
[' text_1_here  ', ' text_2_here  ', ' text_3_here  ', ' text_4_here  ', ' text_5_here ', ' last_text_here  ']

I tried regex findall but not getting the required output. It is able to identify and extract 1.1 & 1.2 and then 1.3 & 1.4. It is skipping text between 1.2 & 1.3.

```
    import re
    re.findall(r'[0-9].\s?[0-9]+(.*?)[0-9].\s?[0-9]+', text)
```

Comment: So what happened with `text after pattern` after `1.23`? How would we know where to stop matching before `1.23`?

Comment: You need to use a lookahead if it's overlapping: [`\d+\.\d+\s+(.+?(?=\s*\d+\.))`](https://regex101.com/r/PtxCwp/1) further to match a literal dot, escape it.

Comment: @JvdV text after pattern need not be extracted.

Comment: @JvdV, only text between the pattern (bullet points) needs to be extracted. The last point is usually about conclusion, author, or other trivial details which are not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure about the exact rule why you'd want to exclude the last bit of text but based on your comments it seems we could also just split the entire text on the bullits and simply exclude the 1st and last element from the resulting array:

```
re.split(r'\s+\d(?:\s*\.\s*\d+)+\s+', text)[1:-1]
```

Which would output:

```
['text_1_here', 'text_2_here', 'text_3_here', 'text_4_here', 'text_5_here', 'last_text_here']
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Bullet points can have space like this also 1 .2, 1 . 2 , 1. 2,

Comment: @Prince, right. ammended the regular expressions to cater for that.